# Error getting library(car) in Rstudio for Mac to install

Tags: r, macos

I am attempting to use library(car) in Studio (v. 1.3.1073) on my Mac but keep getting the error message below.  I have installed the missing data.table package and tried library(car) again. Additionally, I have installed the Rcpp package but keep getting the same error message.

Can someone assist in getting past this error? Thanks.

**Error message:**
*> library(car)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘data.table’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.6.2*

Comment: You should update to the latest version of R (4.0.2) and try again.

Comment: From your error message, it states that your version of `R` is either very old or your packages are built under a previous version of `R`. Currently the newest version of `R` is 4.0.2, and it is highly suggested to keep `R` up to date (every few months checking [cran.r-project.com](cran.r-project.com)). As phil suggested, here i'd suggest trying to update `R` and installing the necessary packages again, and checking `Xcode` for newer versions as well (Xcode shouldn't affect this at all).